# Android One as beacon transmitter

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I tried using [altbeacon-transmitter-android](https://github.com/AltBeacon/altbeacon-transmitter-android) to make my android one(Mito Impact) as beacon transmitter. When I ran it, I got error message "E/BeaconTransmitter﹕ Advertisement start failed, code: 4".

I can use android one as beacon receiver, so I'm sure that my android one support bluetooth low energy (BLE).

Could I use android one as beacon transmitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your device is not supported. I have checked Mito Impact and its Android version is 5.1 which is okay but most probably there is no driver support for advertising mode or no support for peripheral for Mito Impact's Bluetooth Chipset. Check this out [this](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter.html) for more information.

Btw, you can test with [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate) application to see if your device is supported or there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have installed Locate Beacon app, when I entered "Beacon Transmitter" menu and tried to switch on as transmitter, I got error message "Failed to start beacon. Internal Error - error code 4". What's the meaning of the message?

Comment: Error code 4 refers to `NOT_SUPPORTED_CANNOT_GET_ADVERTISER`. If you are sure that your OS is Lollipop, which indicates your device's Bluetooth Chipset is not supported by Android (for advertisement purposes).